# The general solution to the differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am having problems in classifying the differential equation $y''=y(x^2)$ in categories like homogeneous, exact, bernoulli, separable and non-exact so I could have the general solution.

Or would someone help me find the solution

Comment: Almost never do such equations have closed-form solutions. If you can even prove a solution exists.

Comment: @Chappers,Do solved you mean it can not be solved?

Comment: is it $y(x^2)$ or $y(x)^2$?

Comment: @Dr. Sonnhard Graubner ,Square of x is multiplying y

Comment: Oh, so you mean $y''=x^2y$?

Comment: @Chappers, yes it is as you stated in the comment above

Comment: Ah, well, that's different. Using brackets after a function name are ambiguous: $y(x^2)$ normally means $y$ applied to $x^2$.

Comment: I get it. Thanks for noticing the error in my typing

Comment: Is there no solution to this differential equation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the solution containes the Bessel-function
$$y \left( x \right) =C_1 \,\sqrt {x} \, {{I}_{1/4}\left(1/2\,{x}^
{2}\right)}+ C_2 \,\sqrt {x} \, {{K}_{1/4}\left(1/2\,{x}^{2}
\right)}
$$

Answer (score 1):

The General solution to this differential equation would be an infinite series:

$$y(x) = \sum^\infty_{n=0} a_nx^n $$

In this case, the coefficents are pretty odd.  Since $ a_2 = 0, a_3 = 0 $, and the recurrence is every 4 terms.  In this case we have:

$$ a_4 = a_0/12, a_5 = a_1/20, a_8 = a_4/56, a_9 = a_5/72 $$

To find the exact relationship requires some art.  I would go with:

$$ a_{4k} = \frac{a_0}{(4^k)k!(4k-1)(4k-5)...etc)} , a_{4k+1} = \frac{a_1}{4^kk!(4k+1)(4k-3)...etc} $$

The etc. can be rewritten as factorials if needed.

Comment: Completely lost here

Comment: would you provide some literature

Comment: Here is the [wikipedia entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_series_solution_of_differential_equations) on this method.